# Does OS/browser treat CNAME certificate based on the destination?

Tags: security, ssl

I have a web site `example.com`, and `www.example.com` is simply a CNAME to `example.com`.

`example.com` has a certificate issued by Lets Encrypt for `example.com` only.

On the web server (Nginx), I have `http://example.com` redirected (HTTP 301) to `https://example.com`.

On the Safari on macOS, a visitor to `www.example.com` will get a security warning that the certificate is wrong, because it is issued to `example.com` and not `www.example.com`.

On Windows Chrome, it seems that there is no such warning.

Which should be the correct behavior?

Comment: To be clear, when you say `CNAME` you mean a [DNS resource record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record). Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

> Which should be the correct behavior?

Safari’s behavior is correct although I am a bit puzzled why Chrome is not presenting a warning since—in my experience—Chrome is historically on the bleeding edge of making sure HTTPS stuff is legit on the whole chain.

As for your certificate, if it is set for `example.com` and not `www.example.com` then you will only get HTTPS from `example.com`. And if you then are trying to use an `example.com` for www.example.com` then the browser will warn you of a mismatch.

This is because—at the end of the day—the `www` in `www.example.com` is just a historic convention and that `www` is just a subdomain that could genuinely point anywhere. Thus the warning. As the website [ClickSSL](https://www.clickssl.net/blog/do-i-need-different-ssl-certificates-for-www-non-www-domain) clearly states:

> SSL is encryption-based protocol. It will secure that domain only for which it has been issued. Hence, if the SSL certificate is issued for a non www domain, then it will secure that domain only.

So if you want HTTPS on both domains, you definitely need a certificate for `example.com` as well as `www.example.com`.